# Sufficient condition for convergence of a real sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence of real numbers.

Prove that if there exists $x$ such that every subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ of $(x_n)$ has a convergent (sub-)subsequence $(x_{n_{k_l}})$ to $x$, then the original sequence $(x_n)$ itself converges to $x$ .

Thanks for any help.

Comment: As you wrote it it can be a little misleading, imo. The claim is actually: a sequence converges to some limit $\,l\,$ iff every *infinite* subsequence converges to the very same limit $\,l\,$ . Going from here to subsequences of subsequences is easy, though a little messy with the sub-sub-indexes.

Comment: @Davide I was trying to proceed by contradiction by making 2 cases- a(n) is bounded and unbounded .

Comment: Notice that you can have sequences where every subsequence has a convergent subsequence, but said subsequences have different limits, and (hence) the overall sequence does not converge...

Comment: @DonAntonio no there is nothing wrong with the proposition. You should read the question more carefully. he is trying to say, if every subsequence has a sub-subsequence which converges to $l$, then the sequence converges to $l$

Comment: The confusing part, @Lost1, being the missing words "the same limit". As he wrote, it could seem to say that if every subseq. has a convergent subseq. then the seq, itself converges, which is blatantly false. Had he added "...convergent to one same limit $\,x\,$..." this could be avoided. The psoter's use of "...say convergent to $\,x\,$ " doesn't seem to convey this idea, and for example Ben's comment talks about this. That's all.

Comment: I've edited your question to make it clear that $x$ is the same for all subsequences. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: Great @julien . BTW, somebody thought it'd be a good idea to downvote this question, Mr. Stana knows why since it is a nice, important one. I upvoted long time ago, and I invite at least one person more to upvote it to balance the downvote.

Comment: @DonAntonio Done, I have balanced the downvote.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First notice that your condition implies that your sequence is bounded.

Indeed, if $(x_n)$ is unbounded, we can find a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ such that $|x_{n_k}|\ge k$. This subsequence does not have a convergent subsequence.

---

So we know that $(x_n)$ is bounded and it is not convergent. 
This means that $$M=\limsup x_n > \liminf x_n =m.$$
(Both $M$ and $m$ are real numbers, since $(x_n)$ is bounded.)

We know (from the properties of limit superior and limit inferior) that there is a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ which converges to $M$ and there is a subsequence $x_{n_l}$ which converges to $m$. (And every subsequence of any of these two subsequences has, of course, the same limit $M$ resp. $m$.)

We have found two subsequences with different limits, which contradicts your assumptions about the sequence $(x_n)$.

Answer (score 7):

Suppose $x_n$ does not converge to $x$, but every subsequence of $x_n$ has a sub-subsequence which converge to $x$.

Since $x_n$ does not converge to $x$ we must be able to find a subsequence such that every term is more than $\epsilon$ away from $x$ for some $\epsilon>0$, but clearly this does not have a sub-subsequence which converges to $x$, by definition.

Comment: The second paragraph appears to be extraneous.

Answer (score 2):

Let every subsequence of $ x_n$   has a convergent subsequence to $ x$  and suppose by way of contradiction that $x_n$ does not converges to $x$  . Then there exists $ ε>0$  such that for every $ n_0$ , $ |x-x_n|\geq ε$  for some  $n\geq n_0$. Thus $ |x-x_n|\geq ε$ for an infinite number of $n$ . This implies that there exists a subsequence $ y_n$  of $ x_n $ , such that for each $n$, $ |x-y_n|\geq ε $ . However the latter contradicts the fact that $ y_n$  has a subsequence that converges to $ x$  .

Comment: Please use [MathJax](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) in your answers.