# Is almost sure limit of Hilbert space valued random variable is also a random variable?

Tags: limits, random-variables, hilbert-spaces

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ complete probability space. Let $V$ be a Hilbert space and
denote $\mathcal{B}(V)$ be the topology generated by the metric $d_V(x,y)=\Vert x-y \Vert$ on $V$.

If $\{X_n:\Omega\to V\}$ sequence of random variables which converges almost surely on $X$, i.e.,
$$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} X_n(\omega) = X(\omega) \text{   a.s.}$$
Can we say that $X$ is a random variable?

I hope this question does make sense..

For real random variables, the following link  argues it does hold provided that the space is complete
[Measurability of an a.e. pointwise limit of measurable functions.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1095711/measurability-of-an-a-e-pointwise-limit-of-measurable-functions)

any insight can be a huge help for student still learning stuffs.

Comment: There are several notions of meaurability for vector values functions. What exactly is your defintion of a random variable with values in $V$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy  $X:\Omega\to V$ measurable provided, for any $A\in \mathcal{B}(V)$,  $\{\omega\in\Omega: X(\omega) \in A\} \in \mathcal{F}$

Comment: In that case we cannot say that the limit $X$ is measuarble in general. But if $V$ is separable then the cocnlusion holds.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you Very much this is very Helpful..
 would you mind if I ask reference relating to this question. So that I can further study why existence of ONB is crucial in this case.

Comment: Vector measures by Diestel and Uhl is a good reference.