# $|f_n|\le M$ and $f_n\to f$ in measure implies $|f|\le M$ a.e.?

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

Is it true that $|f_n|\le M$ and $f_n\to f$ in measure implies $|f|\le M$ a.e.?  It appears so to me, as justified below.  I'd appreciate it if someone can confirm or refute it for me.

Let $A\triangleq \{x:|f(x)|>M\}$.  We want to show $\mu(A)=0$.  Let $A_k\triangleq \{x:|f(x)|>M+\frac{1}{k}\}, k\in\mathbb N.$  Then $A=\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k$, and $A_{k}\subset A_{k+1}$.  Therefore, $\mu(A)=\lim_{k\to \infty}\mu(A_k).$

Now consider $E_n\triangleq\{x:|f_n(x)-f(x)|>\frac{1}{k}\}$.  Clearly $A_k \subset E_n$, so $\mu(A_k)\le \mu(E_n)$ for any $n$.  But $\mu(E_n)\to 0$, since $f_n\to f$ in measure.  So $\mu(A_k)=0$ for any $k$, and hence $\mu(A)=0.$

Is this proof correct?  Are there flaws or simpler proof?  Thanks a lot!

Comment: A sketchy idea: convergence in measure implies convergence a.e. of a subsequence. Restricting yourself to this subsequence $(f_{\varphi(n)})_n$, you have for almost every $x$ that $$M\geq \lvert f_{\varphi(n)}(x)\rvert \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \lvert f(x)\rvert$$ giving the conclusion. (I may have missed something.)

Comment: When I saw the title of your question, I wanted to post the same proof, but that's not necessary, yours is fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*A simpler argument:*

Recall that convergence in measure implies convergence a.e. of a subsequence. Restricting yourself to this subsequence $(f_{\varphi(n)})_n$, you have for almost every $x$ that
$$
M\geq \lvert f_{\varphi(n)}(x)\rvert \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \lvert f(x)\rvert
$$
giving the conclusion.

Comment: **NB:** I may have missed something. Feel free to point out any gap in the above argument, if any.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  Do we need a finite measure space for the a.e. convergence of a subsequence to hold?  c.f. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1006091/235690

Comment: @syeh_106 Not necessarily -- see e.g. Theorem 0.3 of [these lecture notes](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-125-measure-and-integration-fall-2003/lecture-notes/18125_lec13.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

Let $\epsilon>0$ and consider

$A_\epsilon = \{ x | |f(x)| > M + \epsilon\}$.

Let $\delta>0$ and choose $N$ such that for $n \ge N$ we have $\mu \{ x | |f(x)-f_n(x)| > \epsilon \} < \delta$.

Note that if $|f(x)| > M+\epsilon$ then we have $|f(x)-f_n(x)| > \epsilon $ and so $\mu A_\epsilon < \delta$. Since $\delta$ was
arbitrary, we have $\mu A_\epsilon = 0$.

It follows that $|f(x)|  \le M$ for ae. $x$.