# Weak convergence of a sequence of characteristic functions in general

Tags: functional-analysis

Given $c>0$, can we produce sequence of measurable sets $E_n\subset\mathbb{R}$ such that their characteristic functions $\chi_{E_n}$ converge weakly in $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ to some $c\chi_A$ for some $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ with $\chi_A\neq0$?

> https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4086368/the-lp-limit-of-characteristic-functions-is-a-characteristic-function

> The case $c=1$ is trivial because we can pick constant sequences.

> The post [Weak convergence of a sequence of characteristic functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/283737/weak-convergence-of-a-sequence-of-characteristic-functions) implies that we can do it to $p=2$ and $c=\frac{1}{2}$.

> The case $c>1,1\leq p\leq \infty$ is impossible. Since $\chi_A\in L^q(\mathbb{R})$ for all $1\leq q\leq\infty$, the condition $\chi_{E_n}\rightharpoonup 2\chi_A$ implies that
> $$|E_n\cap A|=(\chi_{E_n},\chi_A)\rightarrow(c\chi_A,\chi_A)=c\cdot|A|$$
> which is absurd when $c>1$. Here one recalls $g\mapsto\int_{\mathbb{R}}g\chi_A\text{d}x$ is well-defined in $(L^p(\mathbb{R}))^*$.

How about other cases?