# Convergence in $L^2$ norm implies convergent subsequence a.e.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $\{f_n\} \subset L^2(\mathbb{R})$ is a sequence of functions converging to $0$ in the $L^2$ norm. I.e.,

$$\bigg(\int_{\mathbb{R}} \vert f_n(x) \vert^2\bigg)^{\frac{1}{2}} \rightarrow 0; \space \text{as $n$ tends to $\infty$}$$

Prove there exists a convergent subsequence converging to $0$ a.e.

My thoughts, since $L^2$ is a metric space, use the triangle inequality on $0,f_n,f_{n_k}$? But how to contstruct the $f_{n_k}$? Sorry if this is a duplicate, I couldn't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We recall a few facts:

1. We say $f_n \xrightarrow[]{\text{measure}} f$ if $$\lambda(|f_n - f| > \epsilon) \xrightarrow[]{n \rightarrow \infty}0,$$
   where $\lambda$ is Lebesgue measure.
2. [Convergence in measure implies convergence almost everywhere of a subsequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1006091/convergence-in-measure-implies-convergence-almost-everywhere-of-a-subsequence)

The goal is to show that $f_n \xrightarrow[]{\|\cdot\|_2} 0$ implies that $f_n \xrightarrow[]{\text{measure}}0$, where $$\|f\|_2 := \left( \int_\mathbb{R} |f|^2 d\lambda \right)^{1/2}.$$
The result follows immediately once we have this.

Notice that $f_n \xrightarrow[]{\|\cdot\|_2} 0$ implies that $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}} |f_n|^2 d\lambda = 0.$$
Let $A(n,\epsilon) := \{x \in \mathbb{R} \ | \ |f_n(x)| > \epsilon\}$. Then we have

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}} |f_n|^2 d\lambda \geq \int_{A(n,\epsilon)} |f_n|^2 d\lambda > \int_{A(n,\epsilon)} \epsilon^2 d\lambda = \epsilon^2 \lambda(A(n,\epsilon)) = \epsilon^2 \lambda( |f_n| > \epsilon),$$

so

$$\lambda(|f_n| > \epsilon) < \frac{\|f_n\|_2^2}{\epsilon^2}.$$

Now take $n \rightarrow \infty$ and we have convergence in measure.

Comment: so first you're showing the $f_n$ converge in measure, then using the fact that this implies there exists a convergent subsequence a.e., which is the link you provided, correct?

Comment: That is correct (the fact about convergence in measure can be found in most measure theory textbooks).

Comment: Yes, I have proven the fact for an exam once, thanks so much!!