# Bartle's theorem 7.6: "If a sequence $(f_n)$ converges in measure to $f$, then some subsequence converges almost everywhere to $f$"

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, cauchy-sequences, almost-everywhere

[image]

Why in the theorem taken a Cauchy in measure sequence and not any sequence that converges in measure? Before state the theorem, the text says "we shall now prove a result due to F. Riesz that implies that if a sequence $(f_n)$ converges in measure to $f$, then some subsequence converges almost everywhere to $f$". Every convergent sequence in measure is cauchy in measure? Otherwise, I do not see how this theorem justifies the fact that in reality for any sequence of functions convergent in measure there is a subsequence that converges almost everywhere.

I saw that to prove this statement it is not even necessary for the sequence to be Cauchy in measure, as shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1006091/convergence-in-measure-implies-convergence-almost-everywhere-of-a-subsequence).

I would be very grateful if you clarify my doubt.

Comment: It shows that a sequence which is Cauchy in measure actually converges in measure, which is a stronger assertion than starting with a sequence that is convergent in measure.

Comment: @copper.hat Why is a stronger assertion?

Comment: Well, I should have written "apparent" or similar, since being Cauchy (as above) and converging are equivalent. But a priori it is not obvious (to me) that being Cauchy in measure means that there is some point that the sequence converges to (in measure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $(f_n:n\in\mathbb{N})$ is a sequence in $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ and if it converges in measure to $f$, then $(f_n:n\in\mathbb{N})$ is a Cauchy sequence with respect to convergence in measure $\mu$. Indeed, since $f_n\rightarrow f$ in measure, for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N_{\epsilon}>0$ such that $\mu\{x:|f_n(x)-f(x)|\geq\frac{\epsilon}{2}\}<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ for $n\geq N_{\epsilon}$. Then for $m,n\geq N_{\epsilon}$ we have $$\mu\{x:|f_m(x)-f_n(x)|\geq\epsilon\}\leq\mu\{x:|f_m(x)-f(x)|\geq\frac{\epsilon}{2}\}+ \mu\{x:|f_n(x)-f(x)|\geq\frac{\epsilon}{2}\}<\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon. $$