# Does convergence of integrable functions $f_n$ in measure to $f$, imply $f$ is integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Suppose for a sequence of functions $\{ f_n\}$ we have that $|f_n | \leq g$ where $g\in L^1$. If $f_n \to f$ in measure, is it necessarily true that $| f | \leq g$?

This seems like it must be true, and intuitively makes sense. I can't seem to prove it though or come up with a counterexample. My proof thus far is: Let $\epsilon > 0$. Then
$$| f| = |f - f_n + f_n | \leq | f - f_n | + |f_n| \leq g + | f - f_n |$$
where the latter term can be made $< \epsilon$ but an arbitrarily small set. But this does not show that $|f| \leq g$ as this does not hold on the entire domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One has $f_{n_k} \to f$ almost everywhere and thus $|f|\leq g$, so that $f\in L^1$.

Comment: For people unaware of this fact, see here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1006091/convergence-in-measure-implies-convergence-almost-everywhere-of-a-subsequence

Comment: Makes sense. I would just clarify that $| f| \leq g$ a.e., not everywhere. But this doesn't change the fact that $f \in L^1$.