# Question from Folland on modes of convergence

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral

I have been reading through Folland, and I am having a hard time answering the following question.  Any help will be much appreciated.

Suppose $\lvert f_n \rvert \leq g \in L^1$ and $f_n \rightarrow f$ in measure.

Prove the following:

(a) $\int f = \lim\int f_n.$

(b) $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $L^1.$

Comment: Measurability of $f_n$ is an implicit assumption.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: dominated convergence on a subsequence.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206851/generalisation-of-dominated-convergence-theorem/207008#207008) is a possible way when the space is assumed $\sigma$-finite. It can always be assumed as we can write $S=\bigcup_{n\geqslant 1}\{x, |g(x)|>n^{-1}\}$ and work with $S$ as underlying space.