# Combining convergence in probability and the means of the positive sequence of r.v. implies convergence in L 1

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $\{X_n\}$ be a collection of positive random variable with $X_n \rightarrow X$ in probability. Prove that if $E(X_n) \rightarrow E(X)$, then $X_n \rightarrow X$ in $L^1$.

My partial answer:
Let $(\Omega,B,P)$ be the probability space. For any $\varepsilon>0$, we have
\begin{align*}
\int_{\Omega} |X_n-X| dP &= \int_{\{|X_n-X|<\varepsilon\}} |X_n-X| dP+\int_{\{|X_n-X|\geq \varepsilon\}} |X_n-X| dP \\ &<\varepsilon P(|X_n=X|<\varepsilon)+\int_{\{|X_n-X|\geq \varepsilon\}} |X_n-X| dP \\ &<\varepsilon +\int_{\{|X_n-X|\geq \varepsilon\}} |X_n-X| dP
\end{align*}
The problem is I don't know how to estimate the second term in RHS with information convergence in probability and expectation convergence.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm not sure your approach will easily work. But, one way to prove your statement is to apply the Dominated Convergence Theorem to the sequence $(g_n)$, where $g_n=|X_n-X|+X-X_n$. Note $0\le g_n\le 2X$ for each $n$.

Comment: $X_n$ doesn't converge pointwise to $X$ but only converge in probability. Meanwhile, the hypothesis of DCT need $X_n$ converge pointwise to $X$

Comment: DCT holds also for convergence in measure. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206851/generalisation-of-dominated-convergence-theorem).

Comment: Also $E(X)$ need not be finite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $Y_n:=|X-X_n|+X-X_n$. Then $0\leqslant Y_n\leqslant 2X$. As $E(X_n)\to E(X)$, we just need to show that $E(Y_n)\to 0$. As $X_n\to X$ in measure, we have $Y_n\to 0$ in measure. We can conclude [by dominated convergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206851/generalisation-of-dominated-convergence-theorem).

Comment: very nice and succinct!