# Variant of dominated convergence theorem

Tags: integration, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

There are several variants of dominated convergence theorem.

The standard one requires $f_n \to f$ a.e. and $|f_n|\leq g$ a.e. where $g$ is integrable. It can be weakened to only convergent in measure, if we impose $\sigma$-finiteness to the measure, c.f. [Generalisation of Dominated Convergence Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206851/generalisation-of-dominated-convergence-theorem).

However, we know if $g$ is integrable, $N(g) = \{g\neq 0\}$ has a $\sigma$- finite measure. Does it imply that converging in measure is alway sufficient, if given a dominating integrable function $g$.

If all statements made above are correct, I want to ask the following question, why most of textbooks only introduce the one with strong assumptions rather than the more general one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, convergence in measure plus integrability of $\sup_n|f_n|$ give convergence in $\mathbb L^1$, as dicussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/428052/dominated-convergence-and-sigma-finiteness?lq=1).

Maybe it's not stated in this way in the textbooks because in a lot (but not all) examples of application of this theorem, we have almost everywhere convergence.