# Show that $f_n1_{A_n}$ convergences in mean

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence, proof-verification

> > Consider the measurable space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu)$. Let $f,f_1,f_2,\ldots$ be measurable functions on that measurable space and $A,A_1,A_2,\ldots\in\mathcal{A}$. Let $(f_n)$ converge in mean to $f$ and $1_{A_n}$ to $1_A$ in measure. Show that then $f_n1_{A_n}$ converges in mean to $f1_A$.

Hello and good evening!

My idea is to show instead that $(f_n1_{A_n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges to $f1_A$ in measure and that $(f_n1_{A_n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is uniformly integrable (because this together is equivalent to the convergence in mean of $(f_n1_{A_n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ to $f1_A$).

**I. Uniformly integrability**

Consider any $\varepsilon>0$. $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is uniformly integrable (and converges to $f$ in measure what is needed below). So there exists an integrable function $h\geq 0$, so that
$$
\sup_{f_n\in (f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}}\int 1_{\lvert f_n\rvert\geq h}\lvert f_n\rvert\, d\mu<\varepsilon.
$$
For this function $h$, it is
$$
(\lvert 1_{A_n}f_n\rvert-h)^+\leq 1_{\lvert 1_{A_n}f_n\rvert\geq h}\lvert 1_{A_n}f_n\rvert\leq 1_{\lvert f_n\rvert\geq h}\lvert f_n\rvert.
$$
So it follows that
$$
\int (\lvert 1_{A_n}f_n\rvert-h)^+\, d\mu\leq\int 1_{\lvert f_n\rvert\geq h}\lvert f_n\rvert\, d\mu\leq\sup_{f_n\in (f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}}\int 1_{\lvert f_n\rvert\geq h}\lvert f_n\rvert\, d\mu<\varepsilon
$$
what means that
$$
\sup_{1_{A_n}f_n\in (1_{A_n}f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}}\int (\lvert 1_{A_n}f_n\rvert-h)^+\, d\mu<\varepsilon.
$$
So $(1_{A_n}f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is uniformly integrable.

**II. Convergence in measure**

Consider any $\varepsilon>0$. It is
$$
\left\{\omega\in\Omega:\lvert 1_{A_n}f_n-1_Af\rvert>\varepsilon\right\}\\=\left\{\omega\in\Omega:\lvert 1_{A_n}f_n-1_{A_n}f+1_{A_n}f-1_Af\rvert>\varepsilon\right\}\\\subset \left\{\omega\in\Omega:\lvert 1_{A_n}f_n-1_{A_n}f\rvert+\lvert 1_{A_n}f-1_Af\rvert>\varepsilon\right\}\\\subset\left\{\omega\in\Omega:\lvert 1_{A_n}f_n-1_{A_n}f\rvert>\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\right\}\cup\left\{\omega\in\Omega:\lvert 1_{A_n}f-1_Af\rvert>\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\right\}\\=\left\{\omega\in\Omega:\lvert 1_{A_n}(f_n-f)\rvert>\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\right\}\cup\left\{\omega\in\Omega:\lvert f(1_{A_n}-1_A)\rvert>\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\right\}\\\subset\left\{\omega\in\Omega:\lvert f_n-f\rvert>\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\right\}\cup\underbrace{\left\{\omega\in\Omega:\lvert 1_{A_n}-1_A\rvert=1\right\}}_{=\left\{\omega\in\Omega:\lvert 1_{A_n}-1_A\rvert>\lambda\right\}\text{ for a }0<\lambda<1}.
$$
So it is
$$
\mu(\left\{\omega\in\Omega:\lvert 1_{A_n}f_n-1_Af\rvert>\varepsilon\right\})\leq\mu(\left\{\omega\in\Omega:\lvert f_n-f\rvert>\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\right\}\cup\left\{\omega\in\Omega:\lvert 1_{A_n}-1_A\rvert>\lambda\right\})\\\leq\underbrace{\mu(\left\{\omega\in\Omega:\lvert f_n-f\rvert>\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\right\})}_{\to 0}+\underbrace{\mu(\left\{\omega\in\Omega:\lvert 1_{A_n}-1_A\rvert>\lambda\right\})}_{\to 0}\to 0
$$
$$
\Longrightarrow \mu(\left\{\omega\in\Omega:\lvert 1_{A_n}f_n-1_Af\rvert>\varepsilon\right\})\to 0
$$

From I. and II. it follows that $(1_{A_n}f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges to $1_Af$ in mean.

*Could you pls say me if my proof is allright?*

With best wishes for X-mas,

math12

Comment: part 2 is correct. In fact just helped someone else to do this...

Comment: Dont quite follow part 1. What is h?

Comment: Why so you assume fn is uniformly integrable?

Comment: Yes, I saw that you helped in another thread to clarify the convergence in measure. It inspired me, so thank you for that!

Comment: You need to tell me, are you proving this for finite measures or infinite measures? Also i assume $\int f_n <\infty$?

Comment: I can see a proof if the space is sigma finite, but not an arbitary measure space

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206851/generalisation-of-dominated-convergence-theorem/358344#358344 this would make my argument still valid, but only for sigma finite spaces.

Answer (score 0):

[Does uniform integrability plus convergence in measure imply convergence in $L^1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/618714/does-uniform-integrability-plus-convergence-in-measure-imply-convergence-in-l1?noredirect=1#comment1303317_618714)

See this. Your assertion about conv in mean, measure, UI is false.

Comment: Is the definition you use for UI really the same that I use?

Comment: @math12 yes... Read the post...

Comment: Your definition there is, that $\sup_f\int_{\lvert f\rvert > h}\lvert f\rvert\, d\mu$ goes to $0$ if $h\to\infty$, right? Our definition is for any $\varepsilon>0$ there is a nonnegative, integrable function $h$ so that $\sup_f\int_{\lvert f\rvert\geq h}\lvert f\rvert\, d\mu<\varepsilon$. Is that really the same?

Comment: @math12 notice that when you make h bigger, you are integrating over a smaller set... Your statement says smaller than any epsilon, how is that different to converging to 0 in my statements?