# Convergence in measure instead of almost everywhere convergence in DCT

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(X, M ,\mu)$ be an arbitrary measure space. Dominated convergence theorem requires some sequence of integrable functions  to converges to some function f almost everywhere.

However, if $f^n$ converges to some function $f$ 'in measure', then does the DCT still holds?
I heard that the answer is yes, but can't figure out how to prove it. Could anyone show me how to prove it?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206851/generalisation-of-dominated-convergence-theorem .