# If $X_n\overset{p}{\rightarrow}X$ and $\mathbb E(X_n)\rightarrow\mathbb E(X)$ then $\mathbb E|X_n−X|\rightarrow0$

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

For $X_n>0$ almost surely, show that if $X_n\overset{p}{\rightarrow}X$ and $\mathbb E(X_n)\rightarrow\mathbb E(X)$, then $\mathbb E|X_n−X|\rightarrow0$

**My try:**

My idea was to consider the positive and negative parts of $|X_n−X|$ separately. We have

$$\begin{align*}
\mathbb E|X_n-X|
&=\mathbb E\left(\left(X_n-X\right)^{+}\right) + \mathbb E\left(\left(X_n-X\right)^{-}\right)\\\\
&=\mathbb E\left(\max\{X_n-X,0\}\right)+\mathbb E\left(\max\{X-X_n,0\}\right)
\end{align*}$$

Since $\mathbb E(X_n)\rightarrow\mathbb E(X)$ then $\mathbb E(X_n-X)\rightarrow0$ and $\mathbb E(X-X_n)\rightarrow0$. Hence it seems it should be the case that $\mathbb E\left(\max\{X_n-X,0\}\right)$ converges to $0$ (and similarly for $\mathbb E\left(\max\{X-X_n,0\}\right)$). Hence $\mathbb E|X_n-X|\rightarrow0$.

Is my reasoning correct? I never made use of the fact that $X_n>0$ almost surely, nor the fact that $X_n\overset{p}{\rightarrow}X$ so I feel my approach might not be right.

Comment: I can see why that's incorrect but I'm not sure where I made that jump.

Comment: On a sidenote, I don't believe this is true without $\mathbb{E}(X) < \infty$.  Are you supposed to assume $X$ is integrable somewhere?

Comment: Nothing was stated about that but it could be a flaw in the problem statement.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheff%C3%A9%27s_lemma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that this is false without the assumption $\mathbb{E}|X| < \infty$.  Consider for instance $X(t) = 1/t$ on the space $(0,1]$ with respect to Lebesgue measure, and set $X_n(t) = \min(n, 1/t)$.  Then we can check this satisfies all the assumptions (in fact, $X_n \to X$ surely), but $\mathbb{E}|X_n-X| = \infty$ for all $n$.

With that in mind, let's assume $X$ is integrable.

---

Second, note that if you don't use either of the assumptions that $X_n\to X$ in probability and $X_n > 0$ a.s., then as I had mentioned in the comments earlier, you are effectively trying to prove $$\mathbb{E}(X_n-X) \to 0 \implies \mathbb{E}|X_n-X| \to 0$$
which is false, so the proof is flawed from the onset.  In your proof, this error appears more precisely as $$\mathbb{E}(X_n-X) \to 0 \implies \mathbb{E}(\max\{X_n-X,0\}) \to 0$$

---

Let's finally prove the modified statement.

Consider $(X_n-X)^-$.  We have $0 \leq (X_n-X)^- \leq |X|$ a.s. and $(X_n-X)^- \to 0$ in probability.  By the the [Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/206851/), $\mathbb{E}\left[(X_n-X)^-\right]\to 0$.

At this point, we're effectively finished.  This is because we may write
$$|X_n-X| = (X_n-X) + 2(X_n-X)^-$$
and the right-hand side is the sum of two sequences, each of whose expectations goes to zero.